# Get Sony ZV-E10 camera work on Kubuntu 22.10

Tags: kubuntu, sony, 22.10

I have purchased a Sony ZV-E10 camera and am wondering if anyone has been able to get it to work on Kubuntu 22.10.

[image: Sony ZV-E10]

Comment: Are you trying to access the storage? you probably have to mount it manually.

Comment: @UtkarshChandraSrivastava I can get to storage no problem. I want to use camera as external camera for my laptop

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my camera up and running for a live stream.
I found this article: [How do I get my Sony Cybershot W510 to connect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293158/how-do-i-get-my-sony-cybershot-w510-to-connect)